# Custom iOS emoji keyboard without Unicode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

We are trying to create a custom emoji keyboard in iOS 8. We already created a keyboard with our own icons. These icons have no Unicode characters. But I can't pass my icons with text. Is this possible using iOS 8? Why can't I send my own icons?

Comment: Keyboard extensions can only set text (which built in emoji are). Keyboards like PopKey require users to copy the image and paste into Messages.app. Even then I don't believe images can be sent inline in a string.

Comment: @vks Did you find a way to solve your problem? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Brian is correct. The keyboard extension inserts by textDocumentProxy so you cannot use the images.  A workaround would maybe be to use the pasteboard like below.  Not ideal I know, but it is my only idea.  I had this problem a few months ago and came to this same half solution.  Keep in mind you will need to grant the keyboard access in the Info.plist file.
"RequestsOpenAccess" = YES in your Info.plist file. AND you have to toggle "Full Access" with settings.

```
let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("emojiCustom", ofType: "png")
   let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageURL!)!);
   UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: "emojiCustom.png")
```

Then you will need to prompt the user that the custom emoji is available for pasting.  I know it is a hack, and not a pretty one, but other than submitting your emojis to unicode for approval (and that would take a lot of time and it is just a proposal, they don't have to approve for adoption) you are limited to a type of hack.  If you want to submit to unicode, I have included their link.
http://unicode.org/emoji/selection.html

Answer (score 0):

A different approach that is now available under iOS 10 is their exposure of the [iMessages API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages).  You can use your "main" app to allow the user to build a custom emoji "image", or do it yourself and use the iMessage API to attach it directly to the message.